# Proc SQL Create Table Statement not Working but no Error?

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I have a series of create table statements on SAS E.G. They work in isolation without problem but when I run them together only the first table creates. There is no error in the log nor indication it has even tried to run the second set of tables.

The code has to be run together as part of a larger project. Any help would be appreciated! (I've redacted parts of it as it was very long and commented the part where the problem seems to occur).

```
EXECUTE( CREATE MULTISET TABLE TEMP_BAG_CAR_BASET
(
 REGISTRATION_ID           INTEGER
,SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD          BYTEINT
,BILLING_BASE              VARCHAR(20)
,INSIGHT_BILLING_BASE      VARCHAR(20)
,ENTERPRISE_IND            BYTEINT
,BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO        INTEGER

) PRIMARY INDEX (REGISTRATION_ID)
) BY TERADATA;


EXECUTE (INSERT INTO TEMP_BAG_CAR_BASET
SELECT 
      A.REGISTRATION_ID
      ,A.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD
      ,A.BILLING_BASE
      ,A.INSIGHT_BILLING_BASE
      ,A.ENTERPRISE_IND
      ,CASE WHEN A.BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO > 0 THEN A.BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO
            WHEN Z.BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO > 0 AND A.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD = 2 THEN Z.BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO
            WHEN V.BAN >0 AND A.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD = 0 THEN V.BAN
             ELSE NULL END

FROM [SOURCE 1] AS A
   LEFT JOIN [SOURCE 2] AS V ON A.REGISTRATION_ID = B.REGISTRATION_ID 
          AND A.DISCONNECTION_DT <= V.DISCONN_DATE AND A.DISCONNECTION_DT > V.CONN_DATE
          AND V.CONN_DATE <= %SYSEVALF(%SYSFUNC(PUTN(&ENDDATE, YYMMDDN8.))-19000000)
INNER JOIN (SELECT REGISTRATION_ID
                  ,BILLING_ACCOUNT_TYP
            FROM [SOURCE 3]
                 WHERE %SYSEVALF(%SYSFUNC(PUTN(&ENDDATE, YYMMDDN8.))-19000000) BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DT AND EXPIRY_DT
                 AND REF_RULE_BASE_IND = 'Y') AS B
ON A.REGISTRATION_ID = B.REGISTRATION_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT REGISTRATION_ID
                  ,REGISTERED_SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD
                  ,BILLING_ACCOUNT_CD AS BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO
                  ,CORPORATE_ID
            FROM [SOURCE 3]
                 WHERE (CAST(&MTH0 AS DATE) +1) BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DT AND EXPIRY_DT
                 AND REF_RULE_BASE_IND = 'Y') AS Z
ON A.REGISTRATION_ID = Z.REGISTRATION_ID

LEFT JOIN [SOURCE 4]E
    ON A.PORTED_IN_FROM = E.NETWORK_PROVIDER_ID
   AND E.EXPIRY_DT = 16001231
LEFT JOIN [SOURCE 5] AS F
    ON F.EXPIRY_DT = 16001231

      WHERE     A.ENTERPRISE_IND = 0 
            AND A.REGISTERED_BASE_IND = 1 
            AND A.REGISTRATION_TYP = 1
            AND SUMMARY_DT = %SYSEVALF(%SYSFUNC(PUTN(&ENDDATE, YYMMDDN8.))-19000000)
)
BY TERADATA;

EXECUTE
(
COLLECT STATISTICS TEMP_BAG_CAR_BASET INDEX(REGISTRATION_ID)
)
BY TERADATA;

/*At this point the code does not create any of the following tables but no errors occur */

EXECUTE( CREATE MULTISET TABLE TEMP_BAG_CAR_BASE
(
REGISTRATION_ID           INTEGER
,SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD          BYTEINT
,BILLING_BASE              VARCHAR(20)
,INSIGHT_BILLING_BASE      VARCHAR(20)
,ENTERPRISE_IND            BYTEINT
,BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO        INTEGER
) PRIMARY INDEX (REGISTRATION_ID)
) BY TERADATA;


  EXECUTE(INSERT INTO TEMP_BAG_CAR_BASE
SELECT 
      A.REGISTRATION_ID
      ,SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD
      ,BILLING_BASE
      ,INSIGHT_BILLING_BASE
      ,ENTERPRISE_IND
      ,BILLING_ACCOUNT_NO

FROM TEMP_BAG_CAR_BASET AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT REGISTRATION_ID
                   ,MAX(DISCONN_DATE    ) AS DISCONN_DATE
            FROM TEMP_BAG_CAR_BASET
            GROUP BY 1) AS B
ON A.REGISTRATION_ID = B.REGISTRATION_ID
AND A.DISCONN_DATE     = B.DISCONN_DATE
)
BY TERADATA;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to insert a COMMIT statement.

```
execute (COMMIT) by teradata;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the SAS\ACCESS for Teradata interface uses ANSI transaction semantics. If you are not specifying the `MODE` parameter in the `CONNECT TO TERADATA()` statement, your session semantics are likely ANSI.

As Tom suggested above, either use `EXECUTE(COMMIT) BY TERADATA;` or add `MODE=TERADATA` to your `CONNECT TO TERADATA()` statement in your PROC SQL.